# variable in handleSubmit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to save two variables player1 and player2 when the submit is even saved in player 1 and odd in player 2, the thing is that every time I send the form the variables are deleted. how can I do it? I tried with state but it didn't work for me

```
import React from "react";
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
const cookies = new Cookies();
class Juego extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {var1:'',num:0,nom:cookies.get('jugador1')};
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.handleChange2 = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
  
    handleChange = async event => {
      const target = event.target;
      const value = target.value;
      //console.log(value);
      this.setState({
        'var1': value
      });
    }
    
    handleSubmit= async event =>{
      const valor       = this.state.num + 1;
      let nomMostrar  = '';
      event.preventDefault();
      if (valor % 2 != 0){
        nomMostrar = cookies.get('jugador2');
      }else{
        nomMostrar = cookies.get('jugador1');
      }
    }
  
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="col-sm">
                    <div className="row">
                      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                      <div className="jugador1">
                        <h1>{this.state.nom}</h1>
                              <label>
                              Pick your favorite flavor:
                              <select onChange={this.handleChange}>
                                  <option value="1">Selecciona Opcion</option>
                                  <option value="1">Piedra</option>
                                  <option value="2">Papel</option>
                                  <option value="3">Tijera</option>
                                  <option value="4">cordel</option>
                                  <option value="5">perro</option>
                              </select>
                              </label>
                      </div>
                      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                      </form>
                    </div>
            </div>
         );
    }
}
 
export default Juego;
```

Comment: you cannot use `async` like that. Where is the `await`?

Comment: What and where are you trying to save anything? Is this your complete code?

Answer (score 1):

With the state you can save player1 and player2 . In the onSubmit event, num is always 0 so I have taken var1 which holds value of selected item.

```
        class Juego extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {var1:'',num:0, player1:'', player2:''};
          this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
          this.handleChange2 = this.handleChange.bind(this);
          this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        }

        handleChange = async event => {
          const target = event.target;
          const value = target.value;
          //console.log(value);
          this.setState({
            'var1': value
          });
        }


        handleSubmit = async event =>{
          const valor       = parseInt(this.state.var1) + 1;

          event.preventDefault();

          if (valor % 2 != 0){
            this.setState({player1 : 'jugador2'});
          }else{
            this.setState({player2 : 'jugador1'});
          }
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div className="col-sm">
                <h1>Player 1 : {this.state.player1}</h1>
                 <h1>Player 2 : {this.state.player2}</h1>
                        <div className="row">
                          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                          <div className="jugador1">
                            <h1>{this.state.nom}</h1>
                                  <label>
                                  Pick your favorite flavor:
                                  <select onChange={this.handleChange}>
                                      <option value="1">Selecciona Opcion</option>
                                      <option value="1">Piedra</option>
                                      <option value="2">Papel</option>
                                      <option value="3">Tijera</option>
                                      <option value="4">cordel</option>
                                      <option value="5">perro</option>
                                  </select>
                                  </label>
                          </div>
                          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                          </form>
                        </div>
                </div>
             );
        }
    }
```